# WalletSignTransactionError: x.pubkey.toBase58 is not a function at SolflareWalletAdapter.signTransaction

Tags: signing

Currently, I'm trying to create an associated token account using solana/wallet provider (solflare ). However, when I proceed to sign the transaction, it returns an error saying that it is unable to.

This is the error Im getting: [image]

This is the method Im using:

[image]

Im able to get the associatedTokenAccount Key and provider.wallet object but initializing it seems to be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the parameters for `createAssociatedTokenAccount` are incorrect, try instead:

```
createAssociatedTokenAccountInstruction(
    this.provider.wallet.publicKey,
    token_acc,
    this.provider.wallet.publicKey,
    new PublicKey("So11111...2"),
    TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
    ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
)
```

You can also double-check that `token_acc` is the correct address.

More information at https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/1892778b9ddb46545f0e7982065889ee7aec1bac/token/js/src/instructions/associatedTokenAccount.ts#LL17-L23C59